# cmdlet write to console with out writing to pipeline

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-cmdlet

Is there a way that I can have a class that extends cmdlet write to the powershell console with out writing it to the pipeline?

I'm writing a cmdlet which will write a lot of objects to the pipeline (which people will then pipe into another cmdlet like Export-CSV). The problem is if I start writing info to the console that will get picked up as well.

e.g
object 1
object 2
"I am a info message that has been logged to powershell via this.WriteObjct
object 3

if I try and pipe the cmdlet into another cmdlet I'll get object 1,2, the info message and 3. I need it so  it just pipes object 1,2 and 3.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use `WriteDebug` method or `WriteVerbose`. You could read more on MSDN in: [Adding User Messages to Your Cmdlet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms714606%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#writedebugnotification)

Comment: I realise this is very old, but some cmdlets do output text to the console. ie `Start-Service` prints a waiting message while the service starts, but pushes the `ServiceController` object to the pipeline. How would this be accomplished? I have simply used `Console.WriteLine` as a temporary measure.